# Hyperlink to a worksheet that then filters accordingly

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

how I can hyperlink a word to another worksheet that then is filtered to show just the section that applies to the word.
I have attached an example of States.

On **sheet-1** there are a list of **States(e.g Karnataka)** that I would like to hyperlink to **sheet-2** but once I get to sheet 2, I would like it to only show the relevant data, **e.g only the rows which show Karnataka.]**

Please help me on this 
Thanks in advance.
[image: Sheet-1]

[image: Sheet-2]

Answer (score -1):

VBA - use activecell.value to define a variable. Run a macro from the hyperlink that takes you to the sheet and applies the filter based on the value of that cell (macro can be the same for all cells as the variable they forms the criteria will be based on the cells contents)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Can you share macro code for this?

Comment: @AravinthS Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.